# no such file to load -- openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openssl

Am trying to load my rails app onto a new linux machine and i have done all the installations required  and the bundle install is working .Now my problem is when i start the server (rails s)  and then try to open the web app its tells me " no such file to load -- openssl "

LoadError in MembersController#index

no such file to load -- openssl

This error occurred while loading the following files:
   openssl
i tried uninstalling openssl (apt-get remove openssl) but still the problem persist.Can some body please help me with it.thanks

Am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using RVM?

If so you may want to reinstall ruby with the location of your openssl installation passed as an option:

```
$ rvm remove 1.8.7
$ rvm install 1.8.7 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl  # or wherever openssl is installed
```

On a Debian-based system, you can find where openssl is installed by running the following command:

```
$ dpkg -L openssl
```

Alternatively you can have RVM install openssl for you:

```
$ rvm package install openssl
$ rvm remove 1.8.7
$ rvm install 1.8.7 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Note that afterwards you'll need to re-install rails:

```
$ gem install rails
```

Comment: same issue, but your solution with rvm didn't work for me, same error after running that script

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with OpenSUSE 12.1 after installing [rvm](https://rvm.io/) (according to website instructions) and using it to install and use ruby 1.9.2.

Specifying `--with-openssl-dir` DID NOT solve it for me. But, after I installed *libopenssl-devel* with the OpenSUSE Software Management utility, "bundle install" complleted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was fixed (on Debian Lenny) by installing *libopenssl-ruby*:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby
```

Debian (did) split the openssl support into a separate package, see [what's the role of libopenssl-ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7707237/246263) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Using rbenv.**
I had this issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Upgrading to newer version of ruby-build by following rbenv documentation ( do not forget dependencies at the beginning of the tutorial )
https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#updating-ruby-build
and then installing new version of ruby 2.7.1 ( previosly 2.6.0 ) and setting the new version locally where I use it, solved the problem.