# what's the role of libopenssl-ruby?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

when working with Ruby in Ubuntu, I need to install libopenssl-ruby package. I would like to know what's the purpose for this package. Is it a Ruby Gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a gem but an extension. Extensions can be packaged as gems, but this one is not.

An extension is a C library (may be mixed with some native ruby code) that allows to use some C API from the ruby language.

On my distribution, the openssl ruby extension is part of the ruby interpreter package:

```
rpm -ql ruby | grep ssl
..
...
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
```

And therefore the ruby package only requires the openssl library itself.

It looks like in Debian, they splitted this extension as a subpackage, and that is the reason why is required by the interpreter package: it is part of the ruby standard library: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It provides the ruby bindings to openssl, without which you would not be able to connect to servers using HTTPS etc.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libopenssl-ruby

Answer (score 1):

It allows Ruby to use OpenSSL.  So no, not a Ruby Gem. http://linuxappfinder.com/package/libopenssl-ruby