# Error while creating new Rails 3 project : `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, installation

When I try to create a new project($ rails new first_app) it gives following error after creating directory structure.

```
...
...
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
/home/amit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /home/amit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/amit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
...
...
```

Here is the configuration on Ubuntu 10.04

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.1
$ rvm -v

rvm 1.10.2 by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.0.21
$ gem -v
1.8.15
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: [This link](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/) may be helpful. 
Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515331/no-such-file-to-load-openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515331/no-such-file-to-load-openssl).

Comment: I tried suggested link but still getting same error. I re-installed both ruby and rails but no luck yet.

Comment: I missed one step `rvm package install openssl`. I again follow all steps and the error gone. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to bundle your ruby with openssl support. Have a look at http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/

`rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local`

This requires that you have the openssl headers present on your box. These are named differently across the systems, like `libopenssl-dev`, `libssl-dev`, `openssl-devel` etc..

Comment: are you sure the --with-openssl-dir=[path] is the right path where openssl is? and have you installed openssl and the openssl headers / devel packages?

Comment: You catch me. By using your suggestions and the link shared by Alex Kliuchnikau finally got openssl error gone. Thanks

Comment: in 64bit system do: sudo apt-get install libssl-dev && rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Comment: Linux Mint 12. sudo apt-get install openssl && rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, and the "rvm reinstall" command isn't recognized, you may need to follow these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu Lucid (10.04).  Fixed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
rvm remove 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: I confirm this to be working on Ubuntu 12.10 as well. I used the *reinstall* variant like so: `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev && rvm reinstall 1.9.3`

Answer (score 8):

This solution [I saw in this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134806/cannot-load-such-file-openssl-when-running-bundle/140125) worked for me very well.

Assuming RVM is in use

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

Remove ruby

```
rvm remove 1.9.3
```

And finally recompile Ruby with openssl

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Finally

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

I hope this worked for future searches.

Answer (score 4):

If you're *not* using RVM, here's how:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions for Mac OS 10.8 (although, these seem general)
https://gist.github.com/joneslee85/5025729

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```